# Ordering appended classes with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to ask, is this possible to order appended classes? For example, in my [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/eatmailyo/24fv49h2/2/) i want to get on mobile look *`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet`* when Im appending classes.

There's my JQuery

```
$(".cont-1, .cont-2, .cont-3, .cont-4").clone().prependTo(".mobile-content");
```

P.S. There's no way to change class order in `.content`

Comment: where there is a will there is a way :)

Comment: No there's no way to do that in a single selector as elements are generally ordered as they are found in the DOM (although that in itself isn't guaranteed either). You would need to `sort()` the elements if you want to affect their order

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you please show some example?

Comment: I added an example for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an array of selectors, and prepend one by one

```js
['.cont-1', '.cont-2', '.cont-3', '.cont-4'].reverse().forEach(function(s) {
 $(s).clone().prependTo(".mobile-content");
});
```

```css
div.content>div{display:inline}
div.mobile-content>div{display:inline;margin:0 5px 0 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Original look:<br />
<div class="content">
  <div class="cont-2">ipsum</div>
  <div class="cont-1">Lorem</div>
  <div class="cont-4">sit amet</div>
  <div class="cont-3">dolor</div>
</div>
<br />Mobile look:<br />
<div class="mobile-content">
  
</div>
```

Or sort by classname

```js
$(".cont-1, .cont-2, .cont-3, .cont-4").clone().sort( (a,b) => 
 a.className.localeCompare(b.className)
).prependTo(".mobile-content");
```

```css
div.content>div{display:inline}
div.mobile-content>div{display:inline;margin:0 5px 0 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Original look:<br />
<div class="content">
  <div class="cont-2">ipsum</div>
  <div class="cont-1">Lorem</div>
  <div class="cont-4">sit amet</div>
  <div class="cont-3">dolor</div>
</div>
<br />Mobile look:<br />
<div class="mobile-content">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do that in a single selector as elements are generally ordered as they are found in the DOM (although that in itself isn't guaranteed either).

You would need to `sort()` the elements if you want to affect their order. Given your sample you would need to create an array which holds the values in the correct order which you can then use to compare the indexes within the `sort()` method, something like this:

```js
$(".cont-1, .cont-2, .cont-3, .cont-4").clone().prependTo(".mobile-content");

var ordering = ['lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit amet'];
$('.mobile-content div').sort(function(a, b) {
  return ordering.indexOf(a.innerText.trim().toLowerCase()) - ordering.indexOf(b.innerText.trim().toLowerCase());
}).appendTo('.mobile-content');
```

```css
div.content > div {
  display: inline
}
div.mobile-content > div {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Original look:<br />
<div class="content">
  <div class="cont-2">ipsum</div>
  <div class="cont-1">Lorem</div>
  <div class="cont-4">sit amet</div>
  <div class="cont-3">dolor</div>
</div><br />

Mobile look:<br />
<div class="mobile-content"></div>
```

This pattern becomes arguably redundant when dealing with a single set of elements (as above) as you could just generate the `div` elements in order from your `ordering` array, instead of cloning them and then sorting them.

Comment: there is way to, I sort a div classes not content, like in your example?

Comment: You can sort on any attribute or property of the element you like, just amend the logic in the function you provide to `sort()`